# Cut string until specified character. Bash

Tags: linux, string, bash

I'm trying to cut a string until it's first specified characters.
in this case, it's first Latin letter.

I tired this. It kind of works but sometimes shifts 1 or more characters.

```
f=$(echo $f | tail -c $((${#f}+-$(expr index "$f" [azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbnAZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN])+2)))
```

take this string as example: `ã%82¹ã%83%91ã%83¼ã%82¯ã%83«__original_ver.__-Your_name.mp3`

I want to get: `original_ver.__-Your_name.mp3`
I tend to get this instead: `ver.__-Your_name.mp3`

Is there a better method? if so, some explanation is always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
f=$(shopt -s extglob; LC_ALL=C; echo "${f##+([^[:alpha:]])}")
```

```
f=$(shopt -s extglob; LC_ALL=C; echo "${f/#+([^[:alpha:]])}")
```

or [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
f=$(LC_ALL=C sed -r 's/^[^[:alpha:]]+//' <<< "$f")
```

Setting `LC_ALL` to `C` is mandatory, otherwise `[[:alpha:]]` might match wrong characters.